# Overflow hidden with nested overflow scroll not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a div not being clipped to the parent even though it has `overflow: hidden`.

I've looked through the `overflow: hidden` questions here on stackoverflow but most of them either have problems with `position` or seem to suggest that my code should work.

Here's a MWE, you can find the **jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/huocukw7/1/)**:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="scroller">
    <div id="child">
      meh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#parent {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

#### What I expect

`#parent` has `overflow: hidden` so `#scroller` gets clipped to the height of parent. Because its `#child` is taller than the resulting height `overflow: scroll` results in a scrollbar.

#### What happens

`#scroller` just uses the height of `#child` and ignores both `overflow` properties.

#### What about simple workarounds?

- In my real world problem there is multiple `<div>`s in `#parent` so I can't give `#scroller` a height.
- The html is generated automatically so I can't just remove `#scroller`.

Thanks for all help,
Stefan

## ANSWER

There actually is a CSS-only answer in the comments with `display: flex`. See:

https://jsfiddle.net/huocukw7/6/

```css
#parent {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow:1;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

Comment: show us your real world example otherwise we cannot help - ie are they nested, are they other sections within the parent? - it may be a case of giving these multiple divs a height too

Comment: @Pete: Who's "they"? And I wrote that there are multiple divs in parent. The question can easily be answered with the MWE at hand. As per Mr. Alien's answer the problem is that scroller needs a height and the only way to correctly fill the parent is to resort to javascript.

Comment: they is the other divs, and no it's not - if you give us the actual structure I can show you a pure css way to give that div a height but if you can't be bothered then well use your js.  I've moved on so good luck if you're not willing to put in the effort, then neither am I

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/huocukw7/5/ - for all intents and purposes that is the actual div structure (less classes, different ids). I was talking about the "they" in "are they nested".

Comment: and that wasn't too hard now was it - here you go, use `display:flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/huocukw7/6/

Comment: I'd say you could have posted your answer to my original question and it wouldn't have made the slightest difference. :P But thanks for a brilliant solution. Do you want to turn it into an answer? :)

Comment: ha, didn't think about that - I was going the height route too In relation to your original code!  I'll leave it as it is below as that answers what you have in the question, but if anyone reads the comments, then they can see the progression through the comment fiddles

Comment: Added it to the question in an edit. EDIT: And posted it as an answer because that's what I tend to read first on stackoverflow. I now feel dirty stealing your answer. :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is provide `height` to your `#scroller`

```css
#scroller {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/huocukw7/3/)

---

As per your point - *In my real world problem there is multiple s in #parent so I can't give #scroller a height.*

There is no other way you can make it scrollable without assigning a `height` to it. Without that, it will stretch until the child element ends which won't make your wrapper scrollable.

You can use JavaSript here, to calculate the `height` on runtime and append it to the element.

Comment: Thanks. I feared I'd have to resort to javascript because of CSS's shortcomings. It's good to have confirmation at least.

Answer (score 11):

There actually is a CSS-only answer in the comments with `display: flex`. See:

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="something">
    div of varying height
  </div>
  <div id="scroller">
    <div id="child">
      meh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you said you can't add an explicit height to #scroller, what about adding `height:inherit;`. That has the desired effect of adding a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that's the same as adding `height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - I had this same issue using Foundation's `Reveal` overlay.

`body.is-reveal-open` had `overflow: hidden;`

`.reveal-overlay` had `overflow-y: scroll;` (<-- this was the culprit)

and my child element which I wanted to have a scrollbox had a large explicit height, a smaller max height, and `overflow: scroll`.

After much debugging I narrowed down the issue and this ended up fixing it:

```
.reveal-overlay {
  overflow: hidden; // changed from overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Don't ask me why this worked, I have no clue. But it did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for Bootstrap 4 user, what you need to concern is only how to place the correct Flex-related class in the right place. Since `parent` has only 1 direct child, it is quite simple:

**HTML**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" id="parent">
  <div class="h-100" id="scroller">
    <div id="child">
      meh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (You don't need to do anything with CSS, I just copy it from the question)

```
#parent {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

One more tip: if you have multiple direct children under `parent` and require the `scroller` to fill the remaining height of the `parent <div>`, then you will need to apply `flex-grow-1` class instead of `h-100` to the `scroller`. (For those who are familiar with android development, the `flex-grow-1` have the similar effect as `layout_height=0dp` or `layout_width=0dp` in a constraintlayout)