# position absolute removes the vertical scroll from an element

Tags: html, css

My code is as shown below:

xyz.html

```
<div class='home-container'>

    <div style="width:100%;height:auto;display: flex;flex-direction: row;z-index:400">

    <div class="menu-main"></div>


</div>
```

xyz.css

```
.home-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}


.home-container .menu-main {
    width: 43%;
    height:3000px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    left: 300px;
}
```

But somehow, as soon as I insert `position:absolute` in `menu-main`, it looses its scrolling capabilities. So how can I acheive both scrolling and position absolute at the same time?

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle and show?

Comment: It is showing scroll for me. Your markup is not valid. It is missing end closing of first nested child.

Comment: This might help you, there was a similar issue. Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656623/position-absolute-scrolling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the style property `position:relative;`in your Parent Div(not in container) like below.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;display: flex;flex-direction: row;z-index:400;position:relative;">
```

and also if you want horizontal scrolling also add  `overflow-x: scroll;` in your CSS. Like below...

```css
.home-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
.home-container .menu-main {
    width: 43%;
    height:3000px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='home-container'>
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;display: flex;flex-direction: row;z-index:400;position:relative;">
<div class="menu-main"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this add a position:relative; for the parent div.

```css
.home-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
.home-container .menu-main {
    width: 43%;
    height:3000px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='home-container'>
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;display: flex;flex-direction: row;z-index:400;position:relative;">
<div class="menu-main"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
.home-container {
height: 100vh;
background: #fcfcfc;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.home-container .menu-main {
    width: 53%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='home-container'>
<div>
<div class="menu-main"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
        <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { margin: 0px; }
    .home-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .home-container .menu-main {
        width: 53%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='home-container'>
    <div>
    <div class="menu-main"></div>
    </div>`enter code here`
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```