# flexbox - equal height video + playlist

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a video playlist page that has two columns - the main video + metadata, and the playlist.

The metadata (title / author / description) varies in length, as does the playlist.

We need to account for the following conditions:

- if the video column is longer than the playlist column, both columns are equal height (default behavior, currently works)
- if the playlist column is longer than the video player column, the playlist column needs to scroll so both columns have the same height

  - this is (of course) possible with JavaScript, but I'm really looking for a pure-CSS solution

CodePen - https://codepen.io/numonium/pen/bjevVr

Default case CSS (more in CodePen ^) -

```
.content-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.col.video-player{
  width:70%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col.playlist{
  width:30%;
}
```

Please / thanks / you're the best! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `position: relative;` to `.content-wrapper` and:

```
.col.playlist{
   width:30%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Absolute position of `.playlist` removes it  from the general flow and parent `div.content-wrapper` will have height equal to its other child.

Answer (score 0):

"if the playlist column is longer than the video player column, the playlist column needs to scroll so both columns have the same height" - for this you have to make your `.content-wrapper` to `position: relative` and `.col.playlist` to `position: absolute`. How does it works means, Since the `.col.playlist` is in absolute to the parent and given `overflow:auto`, it cant go beyond the parent `.content-wrapper`. Find out a similar one out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656623/position-absolute-scrolling)

```css
.page{
  position:relative;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
   position:relative;
}

.col {  
}

.col.video-player{
  width:70%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-player .video{
  height:480px;
  background: #000;
}

.video-player h1{
  margin:0 0 1em;
}

.col.playlist{
   width:30%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom:0;
   overflow: auto;
}

.playlist .playlist-item{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="row content-wrapper">
    <div class="col video-player">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <div class="video-meta">
        <h1>Video Title</h1>
        <h3>Video Author</h3>
        <p>Et YOLO wayfarers unicorn. Succulents proident mumblecore etsy knausgaard pork belly af gentrify street art butcher quis cray yr. Paleo hammock keffiyeh shabby chic, +1 messenger bag four dollar toast officia food truck sint.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col playlist">
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```