# Create a sticky container on top on another

Tags: html, css

I created this piece of code containing a gold container that scrolls vertically. On top on it there is another container that should be always visible.

I tried using position `absolute` and `sticky` but I don't understand why it is not in the right position.

When I scroll down, it should be visibile always on top...

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div
    style="position: relative; height: 500px; max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto;"
  >
    <div style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
      <svg x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="800">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="800" fill="gold"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div
      style="position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 112px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);"
    >
      <div
        style="width: fit-content; padding: 15px; color: white; border: 1px solid white; margin: 20px 10px;"
      >
        Button text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Position sticky will only stay at the top once it hits the top.  If you want it always at the top you would have to move the actual element to the top and then use sticky

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656623/position-absolute-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Put the container you want to be on top at first and add *position sticky* and also `top: 0` (important). You can also use *position fixed* but it will have some difficulties. [Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)
**appendix:** Do not write your styles inline. For clean code and readability.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 112px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sticky-nav div {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-nav">
      <div>
        Button text
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
      <svg x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="800">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="800" fill="gold"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I need. The gold container should start at the same point of the gay container. 
So the top-left point should be the same. At the moment the gold container starts ant the end of the gray one

Comment: I can use fixed but it's related to the browser  which may not be the desired result because of I can have other elements before theese